# How to create a balanced Tree from a list of elements using this AVL predicate in Prolog?

Tags: tree, prolog, avl-tree

I am studying Prolog and I find it difficult to implement a predicate that takes a list and builds a balanced tree from it.

I have implemented these predicates that build an *AVL Tree* (I have taken it from Bratko book and it works fine):

```erlang
%%%  A program for constructing and searching an avl tree.

%%%  Based on Bratko pp 244ff. 

%%%  Build the tree. 

%% The root of the tree is Key.

addavl( nil/0, Key, avl(nil/0, Key, nil/0)/1 ).    

addavl( avl(Left, Y, Right)/Hy, Key, NewTree):-
    eq(Y, Key),
    !,
    NewTree = avl(Left, Y, Right)/Hy.

addavl( avl(Left, Y, Right)/Hy, Key, NewTree):-
    gt(Y, Key),
    addavl(Left, Key, avl(Left1, Z, Left2)/_ ),
    combine(Left1, Z, Left2, Y, Right, NewTree).  

addavl( avl(Left, Y, Right)/Hy, Key, NewTree):-
    gt(Key, Y),
    addavl(Right, Key, avl(Right1, Z, Right2)/_ ),
    combine(Left, Y, Right1, Z, Right2, NewTree).  

combine(T1/H1, A, avl(T21, B, T22)/H2 , C, T3/H3,
        avl(avl(T1/H1, A, T21)/Ha, B, avl(T22, C, T3/H3)/Hc)/Hb ):-
    H2 > H1,
    H2 > H3,
    Ha is H1 + 1,
    Hc is H3 + 1,
    Hb is Ha + 1.

combine(T1/H1, A, T2/H2, C, T3/H3,
        avl(T1/H1, A, avl(T2/H2, C, T3/H3)/Hc)/Ha ):-
    H1 >= H2,
    H1 >= H3,
    max1(H2, H3, Hc),
    max1(H1, Hc, Ha).

combine(T1/H1, A, T2/H2, C, T3/H3,
        avl(avl(T1/H1, A, T2/H2)/Ha, C, T3/H3)/Hc ):-
    H3 >= H2,
    H3 >= H1,
    max1(H1, H2, Ha),
    max1(Ha, H3, Hc).

max1(U, V, Max):-
    (  U > V,
       !,
       Max is U + 1
    ;  Max is V + 1
    ). 

eq(X, Y):-
    X == Y,
    !,
    write(X),
    write(' Item already in tree\n').
```

So I have the  **`addavl(Tree, Element, NewTree/Height)`** predicate that adds the new element to a `Tree` generating a new AVL tree.

Now I would like to create a new predicate that uses this **`addavl/3`** predicate to create a new AVL tree from a list of elements.

For example, if I have the list: `[1,2,3]`, this new predicate creates a new AVL tree that contains the elements *1,2,3*.

I am trying to do this but I am finding some difficulties to do it.

I have implemented something like this (but it doesn't work):

```erlang
%% BASE CASE: The list is empty, so there is no element to insert 
%%            into the AVL Tree: 

buildTreeList(Tree, [], NewTree, Height) :- !.


%% If I am inserting the first element in the AVL Tree 
%% the hight H of the Tree after the insertion is 1: 

buildTreeList(Tree, [Head|Tail], NewTree, 1) :-  
    addavl(nil/0, Head, avl(nil/0, Head, nil/0)/H),
    Tree = nil/0,
    NewTree = avl(nil/0, Head, nil/0)/1,
    buildTreeList(NewTree, Tail, NT, Height).

buildTreeList(Tree, [Head|Tail], NewTree, H) :- 
    addavl(Tree, Head, avl(Tree, Head, NewTree)/H),
    buildTreeList(NewTree, Tail, NT, Height).
```

My idea is: the **`addavl/3`** predicate adds an element to a new AVL tree and gives me also the **height** of this new tree (because I have the couple **`NewTree`/`Height`**).

So my idea is to:

1. Scroll through the list of items until the empty list (the base case: there is no items in the list so I don't insert anything into the AVL Tree)
2. Insert any element of the list into the AVL tree.
3. If the AVL Tree is empty it has `height=0` so I am creating a new AVL Tree by:

   ```erlang
    addavl(nil/0, Head, avl(nil/0, Head, nil/0)/H)
   ```
4. If the AVL Tree is not empty I insert into it.

But it doesn't work and probably is the wrong way to do this thing.

Could someone help me?

Comment: **news bulletin**: to have Prolog syntax highlighting, use `<!-- language: lang-prolog -->` tag. :)

Comment: @WillNess: thanks for the good news! But does it works ?

Comment: @CapelliC I tried this and that, forever, you know. :) Suddenly I saw "lang-js" in the help, and tried the same. :) yes, this is what I used in the answer here, and it's got colors. :) not all the right colors, but at least some.... yes, I see what you mean. bummer. :|

Comment: **news bulletin**: "lang-prolog" does *some* syntax highlighting, but it's not all correct. Unfortunately.

Comment: but it's colouring strange things. I've done recently a CodeMirror prolog mode, I'll try to 'port' it here

Comment: @CapelliC if you could please fix this here, it would be great news!! :)

Comment: `language: erlang` is better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to re-implement `maplist/N`.

You have `addavl(Tree, Element, NewTree)`. The trees are already in the form `T/Height`. You must start with `nil/0`.

```erlang
buildTree(List,Tree):-
  length(List, N), 
  length(L1, N), append(L1, [Tree], [nil/0 | L2]),
  maplist( addavl, L1, List, L2).
```

(not tested).

The point is, use `addavl/3` as a given, opaque predicate, don't revisit its definition.

The sharing of logical variables between the two lists `L1` and `L2` (shifted by one position) serves to arrange for the passing of accumulated result from one step of the calculation into the next, stating with `nil/0`, until the full tree `Tree` is built in the final step. This is trading efficiency for convenience.  You should re-implement this in direct recursive style, especially if the list of elements is expected to be long.

---

*a note*: whether to use `maplist` or hand-roll a direct recursive solution, is a *syntactical* issue. Both variants describe same iterative computational process of progressively adding elements into a tree by calling `addavl`, using the output of previous call as input to the next. A common *pattern*, which e.g. in Haskell, coincidentally, is captured with a higher-order procedure named - surprise! - `iterate`.

(that's only true on a higher-level of course. In the concrete implementation, like SWI Prolog, one can be optimized far better than the other. Using lists, here, will be probably  less efficient than the other variant).

Comment: ok, but this is an exercise give from the teacher that explicitly ask to implement these predicates using the previous AVL Tree implementation...

Comment: and what is the `addavl` predicate that I'm using? :)

Comment: Ok, seems work...now I will try to understand it to myself and if I have problem I come back here to ask you ;-)

Comment: success and good tidings! :) this is a Haskell `zipWith` trick that I'm using, BTW.

Comment: what do you mean this is Haskell ?!?! Haskell is not another language different from Prolog? (I am very new in declarative word)

Comment: Haskell is a different language of course; if you're not familiar with  my reference, just ignore it. :) There is some similarity in list handling between Haskell and Prolog, and this trick can be used in Haskell as here, in Prolog.

Comment: And about "declarativeness" that you evoke so often, it is a Real World that we live in, and these are the Real World Tools that we use. The Holy Grail has not yet been found, and the programming languages that we use are not yet clear, pristine, declarative, angelic things. Yet. :) :) Me, I'm expecting the arrival of English (TM) (R) compiler any day, but it's not here yet. :)

Comment: mmmm I am trying to understand your previous code snippet...can you try to give me some more explaination about it? please :-)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29134/discussion-between-will-ness-and-andreanobili)